# Preview UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How could I add a preview of the next cell in a `UICollectionView` that is revealed as the current cell is swiped away? Such that it feels like a stack of cards. I am borrowing a lot of inspiration from Chrome's iOS app and its implementation of the tab switcher. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I've found so far is as follows:
Disable scrolling on UICollectionView,

Setup a pan gesture,
As soon as the pan gesture starts, take a screenshot of the current cell and add that screenshot on top of the UICollectionView,
Scroll the UICollectionView to the next cell (or previous depending on the direction of the gesture),
And move the screenshot view with the gesture.